# Symfony 4 + Api platform Cannot validate values of type \"NULL\" automatically. on nativeSQL query

Tags: postgresql, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

i have been stuck for few hours with this:

Doing a simple query on my Variation base :

```
$query = "UPDATE variation SET status = 'FALSE' WHERE id IN
('ba21ac3f-0e7f-4bb9-b31f-dbd49053002e','a656e102-0339-4db0-a4b1-16451c2f1d90','64da7d32-2c9f-4478-bc6d-0b7b6c07af8e','8aba2925-7017-4899-bdfa-bf341c0fccec','6d4374cb-3713-4162-be53-2232202b5809','1810057a-6157-45bf-85d5-ade282b7d807','967d7495-6e93-4530-b6d8-d23640b39226','ebdcd88f-1f58-44b6-a14d-d0db9a564671')";

$result = $this->entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($query);
```

$result->execute();

And using postman it's returning me :

> "@context": "/contexts/Error",
>   "@type": "hydra:Error",
>   "hydra:title": "An error occurred",
>   "hydra:description": "Cannot validate values of type \"NULL\" automatically. Please provide a constraint."`

my variation class:

```
/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
 *
 * @Groups({"variation"})
 */
protected $status;
```

How comes it try to validate somethings. Ps the query is fully working ( POSTGRES - Symfony 4.2 - PHP72 )

Comment: What if you change (string) 'FALSE' to (BOOL) FALSE, so without singlequotes?

Comment: @verhie doesn't change anythings, still works as SQl but not with exec...

Answer (score 1):

If **body content** is empty in request, its possible to correct that if **content type** are is also empty in header request

Comment: Headers content type is : application/json

Comment: Try to add a full valid json in body content, if query is executed so its possible to juste change headers to resolve